# TemplateDoesNotExist in Class Based Views. Django Not loading the template in CBV's

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

Hi I am Newbie to Django. I am trying to learn class based views. I tried to load one list view in my django. But its showing TemplateDoesNotExist Error

[image]

The above is my app structure.

I have two URls.py one is template level and another one at app level

basic_app/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from basic_app import views

app_name = "basic_app"

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.SchoolListView.as_view(),name = "list")
]
```

project level urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from basic_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.IndexView.as_view()),
    path('basic_app/',include('basic_app.urls'))

]
```

I am not sure whether I need to add something in settings. I tried many combinations but its showing TemplateDownNotExistError

```
"""
Django settings for advcbv project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'template')


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 's8yp$(4x%&t^l)sq1r%e&eu56*%hgf=bq4dkwmvmk5n0h44pi*'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'basic_app'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'advcbv.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'advcbv.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View, TemplateView,ListView,DetailView
from . import models

class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

class SchoolListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = "schools"
    model = models.School


class  SchoolDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = "school_detail"
    model = models.School
    template_name = "basic_app/school_detail.html"
```

I think I am missing something in Settins.py. Like I am not sure how to add the template configuration. of basic_app/templates in settings.py

Thanks in advance

Comment: Rename `template` to `templates` in each app's template directory

Comment: you didnt mention the template_name for SchoolListView class.